# LNK4099 linker warning with clean install of Qt SDK and Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, qt-creator

Did a clean install on a new Windows 7 computer with:

- Visual Studio 2008 SP1
- Qt SDK 1.1.4

Then I created a new project in Qt Creator.  I picked "Qt Gui Application" under "Qt Widget Project" and had it target desktops with Visual C++ 2008, both debug & release (basically default settings).

Then I pressed Build, and got....

```
qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj):-1: warning: LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not
found with 'c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\msvc2008\lib\qtmaind.lib' or at
'C:\Users\JamesJ\Desktop\QtTest-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-
_MSVC2008__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
```

I must be missing something obvious - surely the out-of-box experience with Qt isn't supposed to involve compiler/linker warnings?!?!

How do I resolve this linker warning?  I prefer to treat warnings as errors, so... I'd like to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unable to find a solution to this.  I'm sure recompiling Qt would resolve the issue, but for simplicity I want to stick with what is installed with the SDK for now.

Answer (score 3):

The path to `vc90.pdb` embedded in `qtmain_win.obj` is not the same path that is set in your linker settings.

Per the instructions in [this article](http://cldoten.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/vs2008-fixing-the-warning-pdb-vc90-pdb-not-found/):

In the linker settings, `Properties->Linker->Debugging->Generate Program Database File` has the value `$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb`.

In the C/C++ settings, `Properties->C/C++->Output Files->Program Database File` should **also** be set to `$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb` (its default value is `$(IntDir)\vc90.pdb`).

Failing that, you can try cleaning and rebuilding the Debug build.

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator, not Visual C++.  How do I set these settings in Qt Creator?

Comment: You can disable the use of `.pdb` files (I don't believe that Qt Creator can use them) by setting `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = /Z7` in `qmake.conf` for win32-msvc2008. This embeds all debugging info in the `.obj` files. If you need to use `.pdb` files, make sure `qmake.conf` is set up [like this](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_to_build_pdb_for_release_version_of_qt)

Comment: Are you suggesting to recompile Qt?  There's no way to get this working properly with the out-of-the-box binaries provided by Nokia in Qt SDK?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you fiddle with your Qt Creator build setup so that it doesn't look for `.pdb` files. I use Qt with Visual Studio via the Visual Studio Add-in, so I'm not very familiar with Qt Creator. Did the Qt SDK come with `.pdb` files? (My Qt setup was built from source.) I wonder what would happen if you either 1) cleaned them out, or 2) copied a `.pdb` from the `.obj` directory to the directory where `qtmaind.lib` lives? (#2 may not be an option.)

Comment: I don't have any PDB files at all in my Qt SDK desktop bin directory.  Also, I'm not seeing any obvious ways to instruct Qt Creator to do what you say.  Next idea?

Comment: I tried your steps, and got no linker warnings. Apparently, the MSVC build of the Qt SDK does not ship with PDBs (because they're large). This is the sort of annoyance that made me opt to build Qt from source. I don't know what your options are if you're constrained to use the Qt SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Separately installing Qt Library (4.8.2) and Qt Creator (2.5.2) worked here. I no longer get the LNK4099 warning.

Make sure to remove the settings QtSDK leaves behind: the keys in `KHCU\Software\Nokia` and the `%APPDATA%\Nokia` folder.

Upgrading QT Library manually within QtSDK package manager might also work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you move Qt directories (i.e. the ones containing libs/pdbs) to a different directory after compilation. The path to the PDB file is embedded in the libraries, so when you move them the linker cannot find it.

Seems for me that the safest/cleanest issue is to rebuild Qt in the new location.

Answer (score -1):

Add

`QMAKE_LFLAGS += /ignore:4099`

to your .pro file.

if you want to not create .pdb files for your executables or library add

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /Z7`

so debug information will put in .obj files.

You maybe need to delete all Makefiles* to update the building rules.
Tested in Qt Creator 2.4.1 with MSVC 2008 SP1

Comment: -1 Disabling linker warnings does not solve the problem. The solution is simple: Copy the vc90.pdb file that was generated when building the static library qtmaind.lib to the same directory where qtmaind.lib resides.