# LNK4099 linker warning with QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

So every time i build up my program i keep getting the following warning message;

```
qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj):-1: warning: LNK4099: PDB 'vc100.pdb' was not found with 'qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj)' or at 'D:\Projects\Test-2\blah-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\vc100.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
```

I can just ignore it as described in the question here;
[LNK4099 linker warning with clean install of Qt SDK and Visual C++ 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359550/lnk4099-linker-warning-with-clean-install-of-qt-sdk-and-visual-c-2008)

But its getting rather annoying to see it all the time, and the fact is that vc100.pdb gets built but not into the debug folder. As you can see in the image below;

[image]

So the linker is looking for "vc100.pdb" in the debug folder but the "vc100.pdb" file is located in the top level directory. So i'm wondering how in-fact do i change in QT creator the look-up directory or infact if it is possible to move "vc100.pdb" into the debug folder?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, a bunch of problems are automatically solved if you start Qt Creator from Visual Studio's command prompt.
Just start

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

(or find it in your Start Menu) and type path to Qt Creator in it.

Comment: Is this one of the problems that is solved? When compiling a Qt application from Visual Studio (which properly sets up its environment prior to launching its build tools) I get the same error.

Comment: Please, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359550/lnk4099-linker-warning-with-clean-install-of-qt-sdk-and-visual-c-2008#comment10357730_8361486 comment.

Answer (score 0):

Vc100.pdb is the default pdb name for a library.  This issue can be caused by building multiple .lib files in the same directory.

This is fixed by /Fdname.pdb as a cl option.